# Separate single field into name, second name and last name

Tags: javascript, split

How can I split a fullname into single, medium and last name?

Obviously, it is impossible to cover all posibilities. I only want one rule: If after the word there is other word from 3 letter or less, it must join it with the next word.

Also, I am supposing that the fullname has 3 words or more.

I really have no idea even how to start.

For example:

John Martin Jackson:

- name1: John
- name2: Martin
- name3: Jackson

Steven Ponce de Leon Presley

- name1: Steven
- name2: Ponce de Leon
- name3: Presley

Michael de la Rosa Martin Jackson:

- name1: Michael de la Rosa
- name2: Martin
- name3: Jackson

:S

Comment: I know a guy named Michael Harris Heaton Jones Patrick. (He's an architect in Boston I think.)

Comment: There's no clear pattern, why not use 3 different fields instead, like most webs do?

Comment: I don't personally know, but have heard about, lots of guys named Wu or Bo. Last name >= 3 chars is not foolproof.

Comment: both "Leon" and "Rosa" consist of 4 letters, they should go to the next word according to your rule?

Comment: elclanrs: Yes, but the problem is that in the database they are all already in one  single field :(

Comment: Eugene Xa: No, they are joined for words from less thasn 3 letters

Comment: Jon: Yes, you are right, but it is a start. I will improve the result when I understand the function of the algorithm

Comment: I think you should change your rule entirely. How would you deal with names with no middle name, like William Shakespeare, or other combinations like Bartolome de las Casas? There's no exact rule about splitting names: the best you can do is to recognize particles like "o'", "mac", "de", "la", "van" and make them part of the next word.

Comment: MaxArt: I live in Mexico. Everybody has at least one name and two last names. Supposing that the fullname has only two words, I will send empty the name3 field. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A really fancy regex could do that. To match one name, use

```
/\S+((\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*/
```

<s>Then, combine three of them with non-matching groups, but each wrapped in one, joined by whitespaces:</s>

```
/^(\S+(?:(?:\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*)\s+(\S+(?:(?:\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*)\s+(\S+(?:(?:\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*)$/
```

To make it match people without a middle name, make that optional:

```
/^(\S+(?:(?:\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*)(?:\s+(\S+(?:(?:\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*))?\s+(\S+(?:(?:\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*)$/
```

Update: Don't try to match whole names in one regex. Just use the first (simple) regex with a global flag:

```
> "Steven Ponce de Leon Presley".match(/\S+((\s+\S{1,3})+\s+\S+)*/g)
["Steven", "Ponce de Leon", "Presley"]
```

Explanation:

```
/
 \S+      match a word
 (         followed by any number of
  (         at least one
   \s+       whitespace-separated
   \S{1,3}   up-to-three-letters word
  )+
  \s+       and a whitespace-separated
  \S+       word
 )*
/g
```

---

However, I think an algorithm with some string and array functions would make it clearer what happens, and allows more customisation of the matching process:

```
var names = input.split(/s+/);
if (names.length < 2)
    return; // special case handling for only one word
var short = 0;
for (var i=names.length-2; i>=0; i--) {
    // starting at the second-to-last, I expect names not to end with a short one
    if (names[i].length < 4) {
        short++;
    } else if (short) {
        names[i] += " "+names.splice(i+1, short+1).join(" ");
        short = 0;
    }
}
return names; // an Array with at least one name
```

Comment: Wao, that's impressive. How can you write code than the first example?

Comment: It's not as hard as it looks like :-) The overly long regexes (which were a mistake) are only copy-and-paste of the first one, with some extra chars to make the groups non-matching.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
function split_name(name) {
    var parts = name.split(" ");
    var num_parts = parts.length;
    var i = 0;
    var names = [];

    function in_bounds() {
        return i < num_parts;
    }
    function next_part() {
        i += 1;
        return parts[i - 1];
    }
    function part_is_short() {
        return parts[i].length < 4;
    }
    function last_part_was_short() {
        return parts[i-1].length < 4;
    }
    function next_name() {
        var name = next_part();
        if (in_bounds() && part_is_short()) {
            name += " " + next_part();
            while(in_bounds() && last_part_was_short()) {
                name += " " + next_part();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    while (in_bounds()) {
        names.push(next_name());
    }

    return names;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLe7S/2/

It's not the most performant algorithm ever. Regex gurus could probably do the same in one line, but at least this way it's readable for us mortals. *(**Update**: I see Bergi [has just proven himself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787068/990877) to be such a regex guru. :)*

It does roughly what you've described, but you'll have to adapt it to your needs. For instance, it returns an array containing as many "sub-names" as it finds. So if it can't find a middle name, it'll return an array of length 2. On the other hand, it may find more than 3 names. You'll have to think about how to handle that.

Comment: Very interesting, an easy to understand! I will check it. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another working function http://jsfiddle.net/xPzEs/7/

edit: bad link